# I want to when the word of "a" set in the TextView (txt61) ,INVISIBLE the (edt9) and (text)

Tags: android

why setVisibility doesn't work in my code.I want to when  the word of "a" set in the TextView (txt61) ,INVISIBLE the (edt8) and (text12)

```
TextView text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
TextView text12=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text12);

final TextView txt61=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt61);
final EditText edt9=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt9);
final EditText edt8=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt8);
final EditText edt7=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt7);
final EditText edt6=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt6);
String f=txt61.getText().toString();

if(f.equals("a")){
    edt8.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    text12.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}

if(f.equals("b")){
   edt9.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    text.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more info: what is currently the result and what was the intended behaviour?

Comment: Sidenote: "a".equals(f) avoids NPEs